# Sync redux-saga and react lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

React components have their lifecycle (componentWillMount, componentDidMount etc.), also, saga has it's own lifecycle (running as middleware).

Is there a way to sync those two lifecycles?

I think this might be the issue when we would like to secure some components with authorization (on multiple levels of access)

Comment: As a general rule, components shouldn't be "secure": they are all on the client anyway. The only thing to really secure is your API (your backend), so even if a user somehow displays a "secret" component without being authorised (by hacking it, or simply because of a bug), your API shouldn't be returning any data anyway, so it would not display any meaningful information. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can create a HOC (Higher Order Component) that hooks React's lifecycle events and dispatches actions mapped them for redux-saga. In your saga, you may use `take` to sync lifecycle and control flow.

Please let me know if you need a working example. I'll add an example to [my repository](https://github.com/kuy/redux-saga-examples) on Github.

```
// HOC
import Lifecycle from '...';

// Target component
class SecretPane extends Component {
  // ...
}

// Export wrapped SecretPane component
export default Lifecycle(SecretPane);

// ...

function* lifecycle() {
  yield take(COMPONENT_WILL_MOUNT);

  // Do something before mounted

  yield take(COMPONENT_DID_MOUNT);

  // Do something after mounted

  yield take(COMPONENT_WILL_UNMOUNT);

  // Do something before unmounted
}
```